# BlurHash in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image

I am fetching some data from an API and I want to use blurhash of the image until the image loads from the API. How can I achieve that? I can't find any tutorials about it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BlurHash takes an image, and gives you a short string (only 20-30 characters!) that represents the placeholder for this image. You do this on the backend of your service, and store the string along with the image.

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blurhash/flutter_blurhash.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const BlurHashApp(),
    );
  }
}

class BlurHashApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlurHashApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("BlurHash")),
          body: const SizedBox.expand(
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1.6,
                child: BlurHash(
                  // hash was generated when you upload the image and returned along with image url by backend
                  hash: "LKN]Rv%2Tw=w]~RBVZRi};RPxuwH",
                  image: "https://blurha.sh/ea9e499f8080ce9956a8.jpg",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

The hash is generated when you upload the image.

How? There are several implementation:
[image]

For example with python:
[image]

For more detail: https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: Then will I have to make a custom API with vercel to load the images and convert them to hash there to finally fetch the images along with hash codes in flutter ?

Comment: I do not use vercel. But it seems like doable, you can give it a try.